# Can you give an example of how to use PHP __method__?

Tags: php, class, methods

I am looking over some PHP code and I found some references to the PHP constant `__METHOD__`. I read the PHP documentation but all it says is

> The class method name. (Added in PHP 5.0.0) The method name is
>   returned as it was declared (case-sensitive).

This isn't clear to me. Can anyone give an example or describe this in more detail?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`__METHOD__` returns the name of the current class and method you are in when calling that constant.

http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

`__FUNCTION__` will only return the function name.

Comment: thanks @minitech , my answer was messed up because of the markdown syntax ;) damn.

Answer (score 3):

```
echo __METHOD__."in".__FILE__." called";
```

You can use it for debug or log purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Inside this constant you have a name of a function that you are just executing.

Try putting:

```
die(__METHOD__);
```

in any function you run.

Comment: If you're going to die, throwing an exception is a better idea.  You get to specify a message *and* get a stack trace.  All `die(__METHOD__)` does is say "something happened here", but not *what* happened.

Comment: This isn't something you need to try to know what it does.  The documentation makes it clear, `die` does two things:  (1) prints its argument, and (2) stops the script.  By the way, that (2) gets really annoying if you care about unit testing.  You know how many times i've had PHPUnit just up and stop because some code 5 levels deep decided it'd be funny to `die()` rather than throw an exception?

Comment: Yeah, so putting die(__METHOD__); in your code will get you the best idea of what's in __METHOD__ constant, and this is what the question was about? Ain't that right?

Comment: And what makes it better than `echo __METHOD__;` for that?

Comment: You won't always see your echo. For example because of the styling or Output Buffering turned on. Die will always show you the result. Now can you undo your "-1"? Thank you.

Comment: Styling is irrelevant when you view source.  And if output buffering is routinely eating the output you spent CPU time building, you have way bigger problems than needing to know the value of `__METHOD__`.

Comment: your reason for giving voting -1 is irrelevant. using die() is a relevant way if just to see what __METHOD__ does

Answer (score 1):

It is a magic constant which returns the name of the function/method along with the class name  to which that function belongs.

The difference between `__METHOD__` and `__FUNCTION__` is that the former returns both function name as well as the class name, whereas the latter gives only the function name